# Mystery book series whose titles are alliterations and involve gemstones

Tags: identification-request

I remember, when I was in middle school, reading a series of mystery books.  The titles were of the format 'X and Y', where X was a type of gemstone, and X and Y began with the same letter.

As far as more specific details, I'm afraid I don't remember much.

- The only language I've ever been fluent in is English.  I highly suspect the books were originally written in English, but I know for sure they are at least available in English.
- The reading level of the series is likely aimed somewhere between 5th and 9th grade reading levels (roughly 11 to 15 years old).
- I know that there were at least 4 books in the series (likely more).
- The entire series takes place on earth (no sci-fi or fantasy components)
- There are multiple protagonists, including at least one male and at least one female.
- One of the novels included a plot point of ceramic guns, such that they made it through airport security
- Another plot point (possibly in the same book, possibly in another) involved a statue (Jade, IIRC), with a tracking device that was one of the eyes of the statue itself.
- I was in middle school in Utah (United States) in the late 1990's / early 2000's.
- I'm 90% sure (though not 100%) that the author (or at least the pseudonym) was female.

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to add more detail in order for this to be a good question. Those can't be the only details you remember: what about plot, the cover, the language? Where did you go to middle school, and when? Maybe take a look at [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/70236) over at SFF and see if you can come up with anything else?

Comment: I'll add the little detail I remember, @Gallifreyan.

Comment: "*The titles were of the format 'X and Y', where X was a type of gemstone, and X and Y began with the same letter.*" - do you mean the title of the entire series was a single 'X and Y' like this, or that the individual books had different titles like, I dunno, 'Rubies and Revenge' and 'Diamonds and Detectives' and so on?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a ceramic handgun](http://www.cracked.com/article_19781_6-stupid-gun-myths-everyone-believes-thanks-to-movies.html) :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor OP clearly intended X and Y to be [wildcards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) :D

Comment: Those are some great details you added! Now you can see that "not much" may also be very good by itself :)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes, Each book had its own name, and the examples you gave could have been valid titles.

Gallifreyan I'm glad it added something, I would just love to be able to read these books again, to see if they were as good as I remember.

Randal'Thor Yes, I know there's no such thing as a ceramic handgun. :P  But it was a crucial plot point, and the firing of said gun saved the female protagonist's life, IIRC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By intense googling, I ended up on the *[**Gems and Espionage**](https://www.goodreads.com/author/list/233111.Lynn_Gardner)* series, by Lynn Gardner, which looks very promising.

All the books :

- have a title following the "Gemstone and Some Word starting with the same letter" scheme, e.g. "Emeralds and Espionage" or "Pearls and Peril".
- are written by a female author.
- were published between 1995 and 2004.
- seem to be "mystery" themed

Comment: I landed on the same series by guessing that the one with jade in it might be called 'Jade and Jeopardy', but you beat me to it!

Comment: Haha, I didn't guess that far, juste googled "diamonds and " (with the quotes) then "saphire and", etc untill I found this page with "emeralds and". Still stuck on my maybe-imaginary Diamonds and Dinosaurs book though !

Comment: For anyone interested in my Diamonds and Dinosaurs thing (only me, I suppose), I made a mix up between [a kids books series whose titles include rubies gems I have yet to identify] and The Magic Tree House series (with titles having alliterations such as "Dinosaurs before Dark")

Comment: Very, very late response, but thank you @Soltius, that is exactly the series I was referring to!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you were in middle school in the 1980s, this is most likely the novelisation of the TV series *Sapphire & Steel* and the sequels.

[Sapphire & Steel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078682/) was a science fiction series that ran on ITV in the UK in the early 1980s.  Two enigmatic characters appear on Earth to try to repair a fault in space-time.

There was a [book of the series](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sapphire-Steel-Peter-J-Hammond/dp/0352305142) by the scriptwriter P.J.Hammond. This book was followed up by a number of others, written by different people.

Comment: The story I'm thinking of is definitely not inter-dimensional travel.  It was far more earth-bound.  However, I'm now wondering if it's worth looking into this one...